# How to set AffineTransform to rotate instead of shear?

Tags: java, graphics2d, affinetransform

I use the AffineTransform when drawing with Graphics2D. I use it to transform a Shape before drawing it. rx and ry are supposed to be rotation but when drawing the shapes are sheared not rotated. How can I enforce rotation? I tried using the default constructor then calling the rotate, scale and translate but the shapes looked nothing like they're supposed to look.

```
transform = new AffineTransform(sx, rx, ry, sy, tx, ty);
transform.createTransformedShape(shape); // Where shape is a GeneralPath instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use rotate method like

```
transform = g2d.getTransform();
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(angleInDegree), pivotX, pivotY);
g2d.setTransform(transform);    
// draw anything and it will be rotated based on rotate method
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(0), pivotX, pivotY);
g2d.setTransform(transform); // now further drawing will no be drawn rotated
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [Applying Affine Transformation to Images](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23667&seqNum=11) article.

You need to use [`rotate`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate(double)) method to get correct rotation.